# Howto - Latex syntax with \section[]{}: Putting Brackets [ Inside of Brackets

Tags: latex, beamer

I am writing a beamer presentation. My problem is a syntax issue with `\section[Outline]{title}`. `\section` is working fine with all of my section titles except in the following example:

```
\section[$\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module constructions]{$\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules and Geometric Constructions}
```

I need a `[` or `\[` symbol around the G (i.e., [G]) in the Outline part of `\section`,however, Tex throws tons of errors whenever anything resembling a bracket is in there.

All ideas are welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Anderson points out a much cleaner way of doing the same in the comments. Define the command in your preamble as

```
\newcommand[1]{\bracket}{[#1]}
```

and use the syntax `$\bracket{G}$` to place brackets around `G`.

---

The problem is because LaTeX interprets the `]` in `[G]` as a closing bracket for the `[Outline]` part of the command. Here's a work around for that. In your preamble, add the following:

```
\newcommand{\rbracket}{]}
```

Now define  your `section` as

```
\section[$\mathbb{Z}[G\rbracket $-module constructions]{$\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules and Geometric Constructions}
```

This is how the outline should look like

[image]

Comment: I'd probably use `\newcommand[1]{\bracket}{[#1]}` so that you could use the cleaner looking `$\mathbb{Z}\bracket{G}$-module...`.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, that's much cleaner. I've edited the answer to add it in.

Comment: What about brackets for optional arguments?

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping the short title in an additional layer of `{...}` you can "hide" the problematic content from latex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[{$\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module constructions}]{$\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules and Geometric Constructions}


\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Michael Anderson gave a nice solution, but when I tried it, I got errors. Then I wrote this:

```
\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{[#1]}
```

and that worked to get brackets in brackets with:

```
\bracket{content}
```

to get [content].